# ASP.NET MVC Jquery dialog with table show details on row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that popup a jQuery dialog. Inside the dialog I have a table that I built dynamicly from a Model I get from controller:

This is the dialog table html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#btnslide').click(function () {

        });

        $('#dtnotes tr').click(function () {

            var noteUid = $(this).attr("noteuid");

            //*******
            // here somehow i need to filter my @Model to get the item 
            // and then update my DIV 'slideinner' with the details data.
            //*******

            $(".slideinner").slideToggle();
        });

    });
</script>


<div class="widget widget-table">
    <div class="widget-header">
        <span class="icon-list"></span>
        <h3 class="icon chart">
            Notes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-content">


        <table id="dtnotes" class="table table-bordered table-striped data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Subject
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">
                        Type
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">
                        UserName
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="gradeA" noteuid="@item.NoteUid">

                        <td>
                            @item.Subject
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            @item.NoteTypeDesc

                        </td>
                        <td nowrap>
                            @item.UserName
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button id="btnslide">slide it</button>
    </div>
    <!-- .widget-content -->
</div>
<div class="slideinner">
    <p>Subject</p>
    <p>Body</p>
</div>
<!-- .widget -->
```

I have also a div at the bottom that is a slide div. So when the user clicks on a table row then the div slides up.

What I want is to click on that table row and the DIV must show extra detail information from my Model item.

So I guess I have to be able to get the Model item from the table row "item.NoteUid" key, then update using jquery the "slideinner" div with the item model data.

Hope someone can help me. Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can render all the model data you need in the table body and hide the ones you need to with css display:none. I hid the @model.body value in a  so you can so retrieve with jquery

```
$('#dtnotes tr').click(function () {

            var noteUid = $(this).attr("noteuid");

            //*******
            $('.slideinner > p.body').html($(this).children('.body').html());
           $('.slideinner > p.subject').html($(this).children('.subject').html());

            //*******

            $(".slideinner").slideToggle();
        });



 <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="gradeA" noteuid="@item.NoteUid">

                        <td class="subject">
                            @item.Subject
                        </td>
                         <td class="body" style="display:none;">
                                @item.Body
                            </td>
                        <td class="notetypedesc">

                            @item.NoteTypeDesc

                        </td>
                        <td nowrap>
                            @item.UserName
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

<div class="slideinner">
    <p class="subject">Subject</p>
    <p class="body">Body</p>
</div>
```